# Dolbeault cohomology of $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, complex-geometry

So the usual cohomology of $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^2$ with values on some module is 
$$ H^0(\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^2, M)\simeq H^2(\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^2, M)  \simeq H^4(\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^2, M) \simeq M$$

Now I am interested in $H^2(\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^2, M)$. In specific I want to find the corresponding Dolbeault space. I am not sure how to do it, so the first question is this, **how to obtain $\oplus_{i+j=2} H_{\text{Dolb.}}^{(i,j)}(\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^2, M)$?**

**Eventually I want a down to earth reason on why there does not exist $H_{\text{Dolb.}}^{2,0}(\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^2, M)$.**

Comment: $H^2$ is 1-dimensional, and the class of the Kahler form $\omega$ (which exists on any Kahler manifold, in particular smooth algebraic varieties in $\Bbb{CP}^n$, in particular $\Bbb{CP}^n$) is nonzero. The Kahler form has $\omega^n \neq 0$, and therefore must be a (1,1) form (since 2n-forms are (n,n)-forms).

Comment: Yes, but how can I see/prove that dim$(H^2) = b_2^+ = 1$?

Comment: So you're not allowing well-known facts from algebraic topology? ... You certainly can use a Leray cover and explicitly compute $H^{1,0}(\Bbb P^1) \cong H^0(\Bbb P^1,\Omega^1) = 0$, and I imagine with a slight amount more work you could do analogous things on $\Bbb P^2$.

Comment: I am a not a mathematician so I might be missing some well-known facts from algebraic topology but thanks for your answer.